# how to set the datepicker dialog to current time only when "Reset"button is pressed

Tags: android, datepicker

I am using two date pickers to get "from date" and "to date" in my application.When the user first clicks the calendar image button (for both the date pickers)it shows the current date and after that when the images are clicked again it shows the previous selected dates.

My problem is that i want to set both the datepickers to show current date **only when the reset button in my app is pressed.**Else it should show the previous selected dates.Please help me to achieve it.

Thanks in advance.Following is the code:`

```
  DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener from_dateListener,to_dateListener;
       .
       .

  from_dateListener = new OnDateSetListener()
  {

      public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
      {
            factiveDate.set(Calendar.YEAR,year) ;
            factiveDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            factiveDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

            if(currentDate.before(factiveDate)||(currentDate.equals(factiveDate)))
            {
                if(endDateDisplay.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                {
                    updateStartDisplay();
                    //startPickDate.setClickable(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    if(factiveDate.before(toDate)||(factiveDate.equals(toDate)))
                    {
                        updateStartDisplay();
                        //startPickDate.setClickable(false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast t=new Toast(getBaseContext());
                        t=Toast.makeText(Next.this, "To date should be less than or eqaul to from date", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                        t.show();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Toast t=new Toast(getBaseContext());
                t=Toast.makeText(Next.this, "Please enter a valid date", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                t.show();

            }

      }

  };


  to_dateListener = new OnDateSetListener()
     {
          public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
          {
                tactiveDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                tactiveDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                tactiveDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

                if(currentDate.before(tactiveDate)||(currentDate.equals(tactiveDate)))
                {
                    Log.d("1st if","true");
                    if(!startDateDisplay.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                    {
                        Log.d("2st if","true");
                        if(tactiveDate.after(fromDate)||(tactiveDate.equals(fromDate)))
                        {
                            Log.d("3st if","true");
                            updateEndDisplay();
                            //endPickDate.setClickable(false);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast t=new Toast(getBaseContext());
                            t=Toast.makeText(Next.this, "To date should be greater than or equal to from date",Toast.LENGTH_LONG );
                            t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                            t.show();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        {
                            updateEndDisplay();
                            //endPickDate.setClickable(false);
                        }
                    }
                else
                {
                    Toast t=new Toast(getBaseContext());
                    t=Toast.makeText(Next.this, "Please enter a valid date", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    t.show();
                }


          }
      };


}
private void updateStartDisplay()
{
    startDateDisplay.setText(
            new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 based so add 1

                .append(factiveDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).append("-")
                .append(factiveDate.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1).append("-")
                .append(factiveDate.get(Calendar.YEAR)).append(" "));

     fromDate=factiveDate; 
     factiveDate=currentDate;
     factiveDate=null;
        //Log.d("msg","date:"+(date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))+(date.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+(date.get(Calendar.YEAR)));



    }

  private void updateEndDisplay()
  {
        endDateDisplay.setText(
                new StringBuilder()
                    // Month is 0 based so add 1

                    .append(tactiveDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).append("-")
                    .append(tactiveDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1).append("-")
                   .append(tactiveDate.get(Calendar.YEAR)).append(" "));

        toDate=tactiveDate;
        tactiveDate=null;
        //Log.d("msg","date:"+(date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))+(date.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+(date.get(Calendar.YEAR)));

  }   









   /* capture our View elements for the end date function */


    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

        switch(id){
            case DATE_PICKER_FROM:
                    Log.d("current date-on create"," "+(currentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR))+ (currentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+ (currentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
                    return new DatePickerDialog(this, from_dateListener, currentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), currentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH), currentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));


                case DATE_PICKER_TO:
                    return new DatePickerDialog(this, to_dateListener, currentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), currentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH), currentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        }
            return null;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can set default value in DatePicker using

```
dPicker.init((previouslyEnteredDate.getYear() + 1900),
                        previouslyEnteredDate.getMonth(),
                        previouslyEnteredDate.getDate(), null);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @TheReader ..but I am using the datepicker dialog here..so pls tell me how to call the datepickers in fromdateistener and todatelistener  in the button click of reset button..